# Can an estimator of the mean of a distribution with no variance have a variance?

Tags: variance, kurtosis, pareto-distribution, fat-tails

Suppose you have a sample from a distribution with a mean but no defined variance, like the Pareto with tail parameter between 1 and 2, or Student’s t with 2 degrees of freedom.

Can an unbiased estimator of the mean of such a distribution have a (defined, finite) variance?

Comment: If a distribution has a mean, then it also _has_ a variance though the value of the variance might be unbounded. This is different from the case of an expectation not being _defined_. For example, the _mean_ of a Cauchy distribution is _undefined_ or does not exist which does _not_ mean that $E[X]$ is unbounded (as it is in the case of some Pareto random variables with small tail parameter).

Comment: Does this distinction have any practical significance? What can you do with an unbounded varience that you can not do with an undefined one? I've never seen this before. How does one know an undefined value from an unbounded one? Is 1/0 unbounded or undefined?

Comment: There _is_ a difference between undefined and unbounded. The Cauchy random variable is said to have an _undefined_ mean because the usual formula gives an "answer" of $\infty-\infty$ and a more careful look shows that the answer can be made to "work out" to whatever number (positive or negative) that we want. Thus, the usual formula is _not_ a definition of $E[X]$ for a Cauchy random variable. On the other hand, $E[X^2]$ is unbounded for a Cauchy random variable and it is not possible to make its value work out to be your favorite number. So, $E[X]$ is undefined and $E[X^2]$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. For example, the sample median will have a variance and for a continuous symmetric distribution with a mean, it should be a consistent estimator of it (as long as there's some density at and around the population median).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Variance

(Note also the subsection there "Estimation of variance from sample data" about some of the difficulties and peculiarities of it.)

The median isn't the only such choice, of course - various robust estimators should work - at least in the sense that they should produce consistent estimators of the location and have finite variance.

Similarly, consider for simplicity a Pareto with known lower bound (which we can take to be 1, *wlog*). Estimators of the [index ($\alpha$) parameter in the Pareto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) (which imply an estimator for the mean) exist which have finite variance even with $1<\alpha<2$.

Now take a sample of $n$ independent observations from the that Pareto (assume for the moment that $n$ is large enough that the discussion carries through; it won't work at $n=1$ for example).

The [log of such a Pareto r.v. is exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Relation_to_the_exponential_distribution) with mean $1/\alpha\,$. The ML of $\alpha$ in that exponential has finite variance (it has an inverse Gamma distribution whose mean and variance is a function of $n$ as well as $\alpha$). It is also ML for the same parameter in the Pareto. I believe the resulting ML estimator for the mean of the Pareto has finite variance if $n$ is not too small.

(I haven't checked all the details carefully here, though - it's more an outline of an argument --- don't rely on it unless you do work it through.)

---

To address the bias issue:

The ML estimator itself in general *won't* be unbiased (that's not even true for the ML of the variance, even at something nice like the normal), but with finite variance, you can sometimes multiply by a simple function of $n$ that will make it unbiased (as with variance), or in other cases (ones with behaviour more akin to estimating $\sigma$ at the normal, for example), a more complicated one.

In most cases you just find a nice finite-variance estimator and then see how to unbias it if you care about bias (though generally, I'm not sure why you'd pick bias over say a smaller MSE).

[Even with the complicated ones, you can sometimes derive a simple correction factor that makes the bias term in $1/n$ disappear, leaving the bias as $O(1/n^2)$ - which means even at quite small $n$ it may be effectively unbiased.]

Comment: The symmetric example is clear and compelling. I am actually more interested in the skewed case. If the Pareto estimator you describe is the MLE then it is consistent. But why should it be unbiased?

Comment: You may have missed that I responded to your question with an edit to my answer. I should have mentioned that I had done so.